# PIC analog to digital converter to measure more than one battery voltage (with different grounds)

Tags: pic, batteries, adc, sampling

I'm trying to build a circuit that can scale down several lipo batteries (5 cell) up to 22V max to be safe to either 3.3V or 5V for measuring with a PIC microcontroller using the analog to digital converter.

Now the problem is I have more than one battery for each motor and each battery is isolated from one another. There is no common ground between them.

Can someone offer some advice on how I can measure the voltage of these batteries using the PIC's ADC. Some form of voltage divider will of course be needed and suggestions on this are welcome.

My analog circuitry skills are extremely weak so please provide as much detail and or references. Any calculations would also be appreciated.

I'd like to ensure some level of filtering/isolation is present due to the LiPos obvious high current usage and noise of the motor.

PS: I know there are very cheap LED voltmeteres on ebay for this but I want to be able to send the sampled voltages back to a base in my project.

Comment: While Steven's answer is valid there are other completely different topologies. Possible problems with analog optocouplers are error level and cost.  Look at the datasheet carefully.

Comment: @OlinLathrop by 'error level' do you mean added noise/inaccuracy?

Comment: @Olin: doesn't "0.01% servo linearity" mean there shouldn't be error level problems? Especially at DC.

Comment: @Federico: Yes, 0.01% is very good.  Many aren't that good.  Watch the price though.  Like I said, this is certainly one workable approach.  My point is that there are also other completely different methods.

Comment: @Olin: yes, I've noticed. Over 4 dollar at Digikey :-(. I'd love to see other solutions here!

Comment: @Federico: I would have elaborated had the OP not accepted a answer before I had the chance to write one.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - An answer being accepted doesn't mean the answer is accepted forever. If you write a significantly better answer, the OP may change the accepted answer.

Comment: @Fake: The part you are missing is that time to write answers here is limited.  So the question is not what might be useful, but what is the most useful.  Questions with accepted answers are comparatively a waste of time.  I also don't like encouraging someone accepting a single answer after a short time, so don't want to help on principle.  Note that I'm not disagreeing with Steven's answer.  It's one perfectly good way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Olin - I've seen several occasion where the user changed his mind and accepted a different answer. It happened to me to, in both directions. Besides, even if the question is a few days old a new answer would bump it, and it will attract new attention. This isn't a waste of time. I've had several old answers upvoted because the question was bumped when a new answer was added. People do seem to find it useful. I'm curious to see other solutions here, now there's just mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't connect the circuits an **analog optocoupler** like the [IL300](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf) may be useful:

[image]

The input and output remain separated, yet you have the analog value of the battery's level available to the ADC on the other side. The IL300 has an excellent 0.01% servo linearity.

(Vcc and ground left and right of the optocoupler are obviously different.)

**transfer function**
Opamp U1 will try to make its inverting input equal to \$V_{IN}\$, that's

\$ I_{P1} = \dfrac{V_{IN}}{R1} \$

It controls \$I_{P1}\$ by varying the LED's current \$I_F\$, but we don't need this value in our calculation. Since the photodiodes are matched \$I_{P1} = I_{P2}\$, and the output of U2 is

\$ V_{OUT} = I_{P2} \times R2 \$

so that

\$ V_{OUT} = \dfrac{R2}{R1} \times V_{IN} \$

So, even when R1 is drawn far away from U2 it plays a role for it. The circuit might not work if you choose R2 ten times larger than R1 and your input voltage is 2V.

**edit**
The short circuit current for the photodiodes is 70 µA. If Vin is for instance 1 V then R1 must be at least 15 kΩ to allow the opamps to get Vb also to 1 V. A value of 100 kΩ for R1 (and R2) will give you an input range of several volts.

Comment: Thankyou Thankyou Thankyou !!!!
This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @olin I'm open to alternative solutions.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not sure Olin will be notified of your comment. I am, because it's my answer, but he hasn't commented here, and I think that's a requirement. If you didn't see the name hint while you were typing his name, he won't be told. His comment was a comment to your question, not to my answer. Maybe you should move your comment there.

Comment: Thanks Steve, Just another question with regards to your solution. It's recommended to have operational amplifiers on both the left and right side of the IL300. Most amplifiers I know of require that the differential input voltage be lower than Vcc of the Op amp. The Lipos are connected to an esc which can provide regulated 5.75Volts. I can use this to power the left op-amp. Should I be building a resistor dividor to lower the lipo voltage then feed then feed this into the left op-amp which is powered by the 5.75V. Say a 1/10th dividor?
What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Peter - Yes, a divider is advisable. I don't think many opamps can handle Vcc at their input. But why 1:10, and not 1:1? That will place the input voltage right in the middle, where you have the most headroom up and down. You'll need that especially if you're not using a **Rail-to-Rail I/O** opamp.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I power the left op amp by the lipo and have the lipo input voltage present on the input to the op amp?

Comment: @Peter - by 1:1 I mean the ratio of the diving resistors. They will divide the voltage by 2. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I'm with you kind of.. I've made a couple of hundred edits in my posts. What's Most annoying as well is when I hit enter this forum automatically posts.
Ok this is assuming the op-amp is powered by the lipo of course (just to clarify).
My pic ADC will run can sample 0-5V.
So Ideally whilst we are dividing on the left hand side I need the right hand side to be a voltage between 0-5V.
This is why I was planning on dividing down further.
Unless the gain can be less than 1 Through resistors R1 and R2 In the picture above.

Comment: @Peter - I added a section on the schematic's transfer function in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation Steve.
I will draw up a schematic and Post a URL Link.
Appreciate all your help.
Cheers,
Pete

Comment: @self - oh dear. "diving resistors" should be "dividing resistors", obviously. Diving resistors are something else completely.

Comment: Here's version 1 of the schematic.
It's designed to output a voltage between 0 and approx 3.3V not 0-5V as I mentioned earlier (Change of Plan on my part).
[Schematic Link Click Here](http://amicableits.com/lipo_voltmeter.pdf)
It scales down the input lipo voltage by 0.158 approx. Then 1:1 output of this voltage to the right hand side.
Let me know if you see any issues or see issues. Suggestions welcome. I have ordered these parts and aim to test it some time next week.
The LM358 Has two op amps. One remains unused on each side.

Comment: @Peter - Two issues. The resistors looked too low resistance, a photodiode will never be able to supply 30mA. Datasheet confirms: short circuit current is 70uA. The resistors have to be at least 100k. The LM358 is not RRIO, which I recommended. At 30V power supply the output stays 4V(!) from the V+ rail. The MCP6001 is Rail-to-rail I/O and has a low input current, which is important for the low photodiode current. Also low power.

Comment: OOps.. Ok.. I can replace R1 and R2 with 100K Resistors which will give 50uA output at IP2. Not totally sure what you mean by the op amp though as The expected voltage should never be above 22 V
Actually I'll be running the lipos myself at 7.2 or 11.1V. The 22v was merely to have 5 cell Lipo capability.
Will this op amp do the job?
MC33202DR2 or TS464CDT

Comment: @Peter - The output voltage swing of an opamp (look at the datasheet) shows how close the output comes to the rails. If it's 4V at 30V supply it still may be several volts at 5V supply. That means it can't produce a 3.36V output, which you should get with a 22V battery! The [MCP6001](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21733j.pdf) output can go between 25mV and 4.975V for a 5V supply.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The MC33202DR2 Output Voltage Swings within 50 mV of both Rails which is more than sufficient. It can also operate from a single supply of 1.8V to 12 V.
Will it work if I use this Op amp as they are easier for me to source and are their any other limiting factors I may need to consider?
Datasheet [MC33202DR2 datasheet](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/12032/ONSEMI/MC33202DR2.html)
I think I owe you a beer if your ever down under in Aus!

Comment: @Peter - The nerve! Offering a foreign beer to a Belgian! :-) The MC33201 (not 202, that's a dual opamp) looks OK, though it's input current is a bit higher. Not a big problem though.

Comment: @PeterH - I [created a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3997/il300)

Comment: To all those interested. I have sucessfully been able to get this working with the help of @stevenvh. There is a vital capacitor that needs to be connected between pins 2 and 4 of th ILE300. It's in figure 17 of the datasheet.
At 8V Input with a 0.152 divider there was about a 0.1V error. Not bad considered I breadboarded it.
At 22V 0.33V error.
[8V Vin](http://www.amicableits.com/quadproject/Working_IL300_with_Isolation.jpg)
The new schematic is 
[here](http://www.amicableits.com/quadproject/pic_voltmeter_with_isolationv2.pdf)

Comment: @PeterH - the error of 1.25 to 1.5 % will be caused by the resistors not be exactly equal. You can trim it away with a small trimming potmeter in series with one of them, if necessary. The actual values  of the resistors isn't important, it's their ratio, see the last equation in my answer.

Comment: Without the capacitor you get this problem. Possibly due to noise.
[Without cap](http://amicableits.com/quadproject/IL300_without_cap_on_pin2-4.jpg)

Comment: @PeterH - Packet arrived this morning, [nicely wrapped](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CywSx.png). Thanks a million! (Hope I won't be seeing too many optocouplers watching Ninotchka.) Again thanks, looks like I owe you from now on :-)

Comment: A pleasure.. Happy Birthday too!!
Appreciate all the help you offered on this topic and your friendly assistance. I'm Working hard to get this quadracopter in the sky...With this circuit I can now run multiple batteries and detect low voltages via a pic :-) Plenty of work on my part still to do but I'm close to finishing my first pcb board prototype (sensory circuitry, wireless and all). Still more to do on my part, Once the PCB is done,the embedded coding begins... (provided I haven't cross-wired anything incorrectly in the design)
Cheers,
Pete